# How to set property values during testing for CamelSpringTestSupport based tests

Tags: java, spring, testing, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

Im creating a ServiceMix module that consists of a Camel route.

In my beans.xml, I have:

```
<osgix:cm-properties id="companyProps"
    persistent-id="com.company.integration">
</osgix:cm-properties>

<ctx:property-placeholder location="
    file:${karaf.base}/etc/com.company.integration.cfg
" />
```

This means I can define other items using properties from the file, like:

```
<http-conf:conduit name="*.http-conduit">
    <http-conf:authorization>
        <security:UserName>${username}</security:UserName>
        <security:Password>${password}</security:Password>
    </http-conf:authorization>
</http-conf:conduit>
```

I can also access the properties in my java classes if I create a bean and inject it:

```
<bean id="myConfig" class="com.company.integration.MyConfig">
    <osgix:managed-properties persistent-id="com.company.integration" />
</bean>
```

The problem is when Im writing my unit tests. Currently Im using a copy of my beans.xml with test values, but of course I'd like to use the real beans.xml and supply values for the properties.

```
public class myTest extends CamelSpringTestSupport
{
@Override
protected AbstractXmlApplicationContext createApplicationContext()
{
    return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {
            "/META-INF/spring/beans.xml"
        ,   "/META-INF/spring/test.xml"
    });

}   
}
```

I'd like to get rid of test.xml and preferably load the test-properties from a property file.
I've seen some references to PropertyComponent, but Im unable to get this to work :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In our organization, we separate our spring-osgi configuration from our spring bean configuration.

In our spring-osgi configuration we would have the following:

```
<osgix:cm-properties id="companyProps" persistent-id="com.company.integration">
    <prop key="name">value</prop>
    <prop key="name">value</prop>
    ...
</osgix:cm-properties>
```

as well as any osgi-specific configuration (such as service registration, events, etc.)

In our spring-bean configuration, we define all the beans that we COULD use outside of an osgi container, including camel routes/context etc.

For our testing, we start a ClassPathXmlContext using our spring bean definition and a test spring configuration that contains the following:

```
<ctx:property-placeholder location="classpath*:test.properties" />
```

As well as any mocks that we need for the osgi specific beans.

Hope this helps.